# All partial derivatives of $(x-yz)^{xy}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

What is step by step solution for this partial derivatives? I suppose i should use $(a^x)'=a^x\ln x$ rule, but don't know how to apply it.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x-yz)^{xy}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x-yz)^{xy}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(x-yz)^{xy}$$

Thank you.

Comment: I know solutution, but don't know steps.

Comment: Note $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u} e^u = e^u du$, so $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(x-yz)^{xy} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}  e^{(x~ y ~\ln(x-y~ z))}= (x-y z)^{x y} \left(\dfrac{x y}{x-y z}+y \ln (x-y z)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $(x-yz)^{xy}$ as $exp(xy \log(x-yz))$ and then differentiate with respect to each variable using the formula for compisition.